# How can I select a set of pixels by their coordinates in a TensorFlow model and output their values?

Tags: tensorflow

The model I'm trying to build has two outputs: One is a 2D array and the other is a set of values which are the result of some learned function of the feature vector of several pixels. The function is different for different locations and therefor - cannot be learned globally.
For such a model I need to "select" predefined pixel coordinates from the 1st output branch and process them.

The numpy equivalent of what I'm trying to achieve is:

```
import numpy
m = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=[3, 3])
pixels = [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 1]]
rows = [p[0] for p in pixels]
cols = [p[1] for p in pixels]
print('Original array: \n')
print(m)
print('Selected pixel values: \n')
print(m[rows, cols])
```

which prints:

```
Original array: 

[[89 35  0]
 [27 74 93]
 [96 13 13]]
Selected pixel values: 

[89 27 13]
```

This is my attempt to in a tensorflow model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

input_array = keras.layers.Input(shape=(3, 3, 1))
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 3, padding='same')(input_array)
print(f'array shape: {keras.backend.int_shape(x)}')
pixels_np = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 1]]).reshape([3, 2, 1])
pixels = tf.constant(pixels_np)
print(f'pixels shape: {keras.backend.int_shape(pixels)}')
output1 = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x:tf.gather_nd(x, pixels))(x)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_array, outputs=[output1])
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
print('model summary: \n')
model.summary()
```

yields the following:

array shape: (None, 3, 3, 1)

pixels shape: (3, 2, 1)

model summary:

---

input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 3, 3, 1)]         0

conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 3, 3, 1)           10

lambda (Lambda)             (3, 2, 3, 3, 1)           0

=================================================================
Total params: 10
Trainable params: 10
Non-trainable params: 0

The output shape is not what I expected it to be (expected shape: [None, 3, 1])